# Error al llenar Combobox con JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en JAVA NetBeans en el que me piden registrar personas y estas (en la base de datos) se deben vincular con el tipo de documento que tienen. Para seleccionar este tipo de documento, hay una tabla que contiene las opciones y el jFrame tiene un COMBOBOX que me permitiría llamar todos los tipos de documento de esta tabla:

```
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tipo_documento`
--

CREATE TABLE `tipo_documento` (
  `tipo_documento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion_documento` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tipo_documento`
--

INSERT INTO `tipo_documento` (`tipo_documento`, `descripcion_documento`) VALUES
(1, 'CÃ©dula de CiudadanÃ­a'),
(2, 'CÃ©dula de ExtrajerÃ­a'),
(3, 'Pasaporte'),
(4, 'Registro Civil'),
(5, 'Tarjeta de Identidad'),
(6, 'NUIP'),
(7, 'NIP');

--
-- Ãndices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `tipo_documento`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_documento`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tipo_documento`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `tipo_documento`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_documento`
  MODIFY `tipo_documento` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

A partir de esta tabla, quiero llenar un combobox en JAVA. Mi primer problema realmente es que ni siquiera me realiza la consulta, pues según try{}catch{} siempre me salta error; sin embargo, la conexión sí es correcta.

Así lo intento. Este el archivo de conexión:

```
public class conexion {

    static Connection conexion;
    static Statement sentencia;
    static ResultSet resultado;

public static ArrayList<String> llenar_combo() {

    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    String q = "SELECT * FROM tipo_documento";

    try{

        resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(q);

    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error para traer los tipos de documento.");

    }

    try{

        while(resultado.next()){

            lista.add(resultado.getString("descripcion_documento"));

        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error para traer los tipos de documento. x2");

    }

    return lista;

}

}
```

Y así intento realizar esa función:

```
public principalJFrame() {

    initComponents();

    conexion.conectar();

    tipoDoc.removeAllItems();

    ArrayList<String> lista=new ArrayList<String>();

    lista = conexion.llenar_combo();

    tipoDoc.addItem(lista);

}
```

Este es el error completo:

```
run:
         Conectado
         Ha ocurrido un error para traer los tipos de documento.
         Ha ocurrido un error para traer los tipos de documento. x2
         Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
         Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem
         at vista.principalJFrame.<init>(principalJFrame.java:46)
         at vista.principalJFrame$6.run(principalJFrame.java:334)
         at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
         at              java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Como lo mencioné en el primer ejemplo, ni siquiera me realiza la consulta. Y la línea tipoDoc.addItem(lista); me dice el error que es imposible convertir a String. Sinceramente, no conozco muy bien JAVA, pero necesito realizar esa prueba.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún mensaje de error en los logs cuando ejecutas tu código?

Comment: A parte de lo que tengo en los catch de la conexión, me aparece esto: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem
 at vista.principalJFrame.<init>(principalJFrame.java:46)

Comment: Por favor, añade la traza de error (más completa) a tu pregunta. Usa el enlace *editar* que está justo debajo de la pregunta

Comment: Ya lo he editado.

Comment: Para saber más del porqué en el fallo de las consultas, intenta añadir `e.getMessage()` en tu mensaje de error: `System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error para traer los tipos de documento. x2: " + e.getMessage());`

Comment: Me aparece null en ambos casos. ¿No está realizando la consulta?

Comment: entonces, añade una línea más en cada bloque de excepción que diga `e.printStackTrace();` para que diga todo lo que tenga que decir sobre la excepción. QUe el mensaje venga nulo significa que ese tipo de excepción no tiene mensaje incorporado :)

Comment: Me aparece esto:

Comment: Ha ocurrido un error para traer los tipos de documento.: null
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Tu código está mal escrito. ¿Por qué tienes dos `try`, uno para ejecutar la consulta y otro para leerla? Tienes que leer los datos dentro del mismo `try`. Allí mismo puedes verificar si hay datos o no. Por ejemplo: `try { resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(q); if (!resultado.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    System.out.println("No hay datos encontrados"); 
} else { while(resultado.next()){
            lista.add(resultado.getString("descripcion_documento"));
        } } return lista; }` y borras el `try` que sobra actualmente. Observa que  el `return` irá dentro del `try` también.

Comment: Igual me tocó poner un catch, pero lo dejé vacío. Respecto a lo otro que me compartiste, ni siquiera entra el if, que debería mostrar el error. Pero no entra allí. Directamente se salta esas condicionales.